# What is a right way to use like in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-science

I am working on "Not Boring Movies" problem in leetcode. 
The porblem describes as following
***"X city opened a new cinema, many people would like to go to this cinema. The cinema also gives out a poster indicating the movies’ ratings and descriptions.
Please write a SQL query to output movies with an odd numbered ID and a description that is not 'boring'. Order the result by rating."***

For example, table cinema

```
+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|   id    | movie     |  description |  rating   |
+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|   1     | War       |   great 3D   |   8.9     |
|   2     | Science   |   fiction    |   8.5     |
|   3     | irish     |   boring     |   6.2     |
|   4     | Ice song  |   Fantacy    |   8.6     |
|   5     | House card|   Interesting|   9.1     |
+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

For the example above, the output should be:

```
+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|   id    | movie     |  description |  rating   |
+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|   5     | House card|   Interesting|   9.1     |
|   1     | War       |   great 3D   |   8.9     |
+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

My solution is:

```
SELECT id, movie ,description, rating 
FROM cinema
WHERE ID % 2 != 0 AND description NOT LIKE %boring%
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

This solution can not past leetcode test.

The expected solution is:

```
SELECT id, movie ,description, rating 
FROM cinema
WHERE id % 2 != 0  AND description != 'boring'
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Basically, both solution follow the same idea to solve the problem, but I can not understand the difference between them. Can anyone tell me why my solution falls to past the test?

Comment: We can't answer this without seeing the question and the table data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem description clearly states *...description that is not 'boring'*. It doesn’t say “not containing”, it says “is not”

`contain` is `LIKE` in sql and `is` is `=` in sql

Answer (score 1):

The answer isn't accepted, because they want you to filter out rows with descriptions that are exactly "boring", and not rows that have descriptions like, e.g., "not boring" or "only a little boring". Your query would filter out all three rows.

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE %boring%` will select

```
_boring!
...boring...
```

etc

But the description value is just "boring"

Answer (score -1):

you should use ('%boring% ') on your like

```
SELECT id, movie ,description, rating 
FROM cinema
WHERE ID % 2 != 0 AND description NOT LIKE '%boring%'
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Comment: This is a good correction of the query but it will not produce the right result and it will not answer OP’s question

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It  pasted the test. Can you be specific why the solution can not produce the right result?

Comment: @pipi see my answer but in short, it should match ‘boring’ but not ‘very boring’ according to the description (which is also supported by the expected solution)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson is correct; this should not pass the test